# Shell - get android devices into array

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting and am trying to get all the android devices in an array but my array is empty when the function is finished.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr
let i=0

MyMethod(){
  adb devices | while read line #get devices list
  do
    if [ ! "$line" == "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` == "device" ]
    then
      device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
      echo "Add $device"
      arr[$i]="$device"
      let i=$i+1
    fi
  done

echo "In MyMethod: ${arr[*]}"
}

################# The main loop of the function call #################

MyMethod
echo "Not in themethod: ${arr[*]}"
```

`arr` - is empty, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probable problem is that piping a command causes it to run in a sub-shell, and variables that are changed there aren't propagated to the parent shell. You're solution would probably be something like:

```
adb devices > devices.txt
while read line; do
    [...]
done < devices.txt
```

where we save the output into an intermediary file to then be loaded into the `while` loop, or maybe use bash's syntax to store command output into intermediary temporary files:

```
while read line; do
    [...]
done < <(adb devices)
```

So the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr
let i=0

MyMethod(){
  while read line #get devices list
  do
    if [ -n "$line" ] && [ "`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`" == "device" ]
    then
      device="`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`"
      echo "Add $device"
      arr[i]="$device" # $ is optional
      let i=$i+1
    fi
  done < <(adb devices)

echo "In MyMethod: ${arr[*]}"
}

################# The main loop of the function call #################

MyMethod
echo "Not in themethod: ${arr[*]}"
```

Some extra observations:

1. To avoid errors, I would suggest you surround the back quotes in double quotes.
2. The dollar is optional in `arr[$i]=`
3. There is a specific test for empty strings: `[ -z "$str" ]` checks if string is empty (zero-length) and `[ -n "$str"]` checks if it isn't

Hope this helps =)